# What is the ordinary definition of a saddle-point?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathcal{C}^2$ function such that both first-order partial derivatives vanish at the origin. Under what circumstances would you say that $f$ has a saddle-point at the origin?

If the Hessian of $f$ is nonsingular, then this question is not interesting, so I suppose I am really asking when a function $f$ having a stationary point at the origin and whose Hessian is singular there has a saddle-point. Consider as examples the obvious saddle-point $f(x,y) = x^4 - y^4$, the slightly less obvious case of $f(x,y) = x^3-y^3$, and the very peculiar case of $f(x,y) = \sin(1/(x^2 + y^2))\exp(-1/(x^2+y^2))$ extended to $\mathbb{R}^2$ by setting $f(0,0)=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A saddle point is a critical point that's not a local maximum or minimum; in other words, a point $p$ with $\nabla f(p)=0$ and the property that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exist two points $q_1$ and $q_2$ with $\|p-q_1\|<\epsilon$, $\|p-q_2\| < \epsilon$, and $f(q_1) < f(p) < f(q_2)$.

If $f$ is only $C^2$ there's no way to characterize such functions by looking only at $f$'s derivatives at $p$ (since like you point out all bets are off at points where both the gradient and Hessian vanish.) Perhaps more could be said if $f$ is smooth.

Comment: This is the definition that wikipedia, for instance, uses (inconsistently). I myself feel uncomfortable calling something that exhibits no saddle-like behaviour at all a saddle-point, but I don't know where I'd draw the line.

Comment: For what it's worth, the question of $\mathcal{C}^2$-ness is a red herring, there are pathological examples where the function is smooth, the third example in the original question is pretty dreadful, but smooth.

Comment: How do we know that if a point is a saddle point that maybe in some directions (not just in the direction of x and y) this point is minima or maxima?

Comment: I would expect a saddle point to have some sort of stable/unstable (positive/negative) *submanifolds*, whether linear or smooth, rather than simply *subsets*, as in this definition. Maybe with an additional requirement that the submanifolds intersect rather than touch. This would keep [Peano surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_surface) as a saddle surface, but exclude the second example $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3$ and also $f(x)=x^3$. @BenWilliams, is this something like what you had in mind?